# How to shape a distribution?

Tags: distributions, data-visualization, dataset

I have a data set of teams. Each team has a sum of points. I want to divide the teams in ranges of points (0 - 999; 1000 - 1999; etc) such as that the top range (with the most points) is smaller (has less teams) than the next and so on. Suppose the number of ranges is 7 and the angle is X degrees like in this figure:

[image: a]

How do I find the point ranges' limits to form that figure?

EDIT: The bars have the same base size regardless of the respective range size.

Comment: I am sorry, but this question makes no sense to me. Normally one would group the scores in order to see how the teams are distributed across the scores. Your grouping, as far as I understand you, is purely artificial. What shall this plot demonstrate ?

Comment: This plot is just to clarify the question. It will not be used. I just want to classify the teams into groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact angle of the bars will depend on the aspect ratio and limits in your graph, but the general linear pattern can be found using a simple sequence and the `quantile` function.

Here is a basic function using R to find the breaks:

```
genbreaks <- function(x, n.groups=5, smallest=1, lowest.adj=1) {
    sq <- seq( n.groups+smallest-1, smallest, by=-1 )
    cssq <- cumsum(sq)
    cssqq <- cssq/max(cssq)
    c(min(x)-lowest.adj, quantile(x, cssqq))
}
```

You can see the effects with code like:

```
tmp <- rnorm(100)
barplot( table( cut(tmp, genbreaks(tmp))))
barplot( table( cut(tmp, genbreaks(tmp,6))))
barplot( table( cut(tmp, genbreaks(tmp,6,3))))
```

You may also want to play with the other options to quantile to possibly prettyify the boundary values.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? This plots a simple histogram of the type of data that you seem to be describing. It's with R code:

```
x1 <- rnbinom(100, mu = 2, size = 10)
x1<-x1*1000
plot(hist(x1, breaks=seq(0,max(x1), length.out=7)))
```

Comment: Do you need the `plot` call?  Since `plot=T` is default on `hist`, I think you can just use `hist(x1, breaks=seq(0,max(x1), length.out=7))`.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Nope, you're right, it's not needed. It's just a habit I have because I usually use density().